# disable all dates on load of calendar and enable specific dates in angularjs (only datePicker and not dateTimePicker)

Tags: angularjs

siteDatePicker.html:

```
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>Typehead</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
          <script src="./siteDatePicker.js"></script>

              <style>
              .full button span {
                background-color: limegreen;
                border-radius: 32px;
                color: black;
              }
              .partially button span {
                background-color: orange;
                border-radius: 32px;
                color: black;
              }
              .appointment>button {
                color: white;
                background-color: red;
              }

            </style>   

          </head>
          <body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" >

             <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
              <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

              <h4>Popup</h4>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" ng-change="dateSelected()"is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" custom-class="dayClass(date, mode)" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

siteDatePicker.js:

```
        var myApp= angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.dateparser', 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker']);



                     myApp.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


         $scope.holidays=[];
                    $scope.today = function() {
                        $scope.dt = new Date();
                      };
                      $scope.today();

                      $scope.clear = function() {
                        $scope.dt = null;
                      };

                      $scope.inlineOptions = {
                        minDate: new Date(),
                        showWeeks: false
                      };

                      $scope.dateOptions = {
                          formatYear: 'yy',
                          maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
                          minDate: new Date(),
                          startingDay: 1
                        };

                        // Disable weekend selection
                        function disabledasda(data) {
                          var date = data.date,
                            mode = data.mode;
                          return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
                        }

                      $scope.toggleMin = function() {
                        $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
                        $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
                      };

                      $scope.toggleMin();

                      $scope.open1 = function() {
                        $scope.popup1.opened = true;
                      };


                      $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
                        $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
                      };

                      $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
                      $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
                      $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

                      $scope.popup1 = {
                        opened: false
                      };


                      var tomorrow = new Date();
                      tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
                      var afterTomorrow = new Date();
                      afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
                      $scope.events = [
                        {
                          date: tomorrow,
                          status: 'full'
                        },
                        {
                          date: afterTomorrow,
                          status: 'partially'
                        }
                      ];
                      $scope.disabled = function(date, mode){

                        $scope.holidays = [
                          new Date(2016,2,14),
                          new Date(2016,2,15),
                          new Date(2016,2,16),
                        ]

                        var isHoliday = false;
                        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.holidays.length ; i++) {
                          if(areDatesEqual($scope.holidays[i], date)){
                            isHoliday = true;
                          }
                        }

                        return ( mode === 'day' && isHoliday );
                      };

                      function areDatesEqual(date1, date2) {

                        return date1.setHours(0,0,0,0) === date2.setHours(0,0,0,0)

                      }

                      $scope.dayClass = function(date, mode) {

                    var appointments = [
                      new Date(2016,2,3),
                      new Date(2016,2,8),
                      new Date(2016,2,22),
                    ]

                    if (mode === 'day') {

                      var dateToCheck = new Date(date);

                      for(var i = 0; i < appointments.length ; i++) {
                        if(areDatesEqual(appointments[i], dateToCheck)){
                          return 'appointment';
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    return '';
                  };

                  $scope.dateSelected = function(){

            var appointments = [
              new Date(2016,2,3),
              new Date(2016,2,8),
              new Date(2016,2,22),
            ];

            var dateSelected = new Date($scope.dt);

            for(var i = 0; i < appointments.length ; i++) {
              if(areDatesEqual(appointments[i], dateSelected)){
                performAction();
              }
            }

          };

          function performAction(){
            alert("Appointment date selected");
             $scope.holidays.push(new Date(2016,2,14));

                        $scope.disabled(date,mode);
          }



                     });
```

above is what i tried...i tried pushing new dates in in holidays array where dates are disabled...its done in the performaction function.....

firstly i want to load the calendar with all dates disabled at first and than i have to be able to enabled specific dates of my choice....

secondly after tha calendar has loaded and the specific dates have been enabled, i want to enable more dates on click of any of the enabled dates.

example:
all dates are disabled when calendar is loaded
27-03-2016 is enabled when calendar is loaded
on click of 27-03-2016, it enables 28-03-2016

please note: i want to disables ALL DATES and not to disable datepicker.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: done....any person who lands on this page, use the following link: http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/206/Disable-future-dates-in-AngularJS-UI-bootstrap-datepicker.aspx        now set maxdate and mindate by passing todays date...and code to disable specific date is above in my question...you can disable current that with that...done! but now i want to enable certain dates....

Answer (score 1):

here is the complete answer for those in need: (id like to thank @Sergio Marron for all his help)

siteDatePicker.js:

```
     var myApp= angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.dateparser', 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker']);



                 myApp.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

                $scope.today = function() {
                    $scope.dt = new Date();
                  };
                  $scope.today();

                  $scope.clear = function() {
                    $scope.dt = null;
                  };

                  $scope.inlineOptions = {
                    minDate: new Date(),
                    showWeeks: false
                  };

                  $scope.dateOptions = {
                      formatYear: 'yy',
                      maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
                      minDate: new Date(),
                      startingDay: 1
                    };

                    // Disable weekend selection
                    function disabledasda(data) {
                      var date = data.date,
                        mode = data.mode;
                      return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
                    }

                  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
                    $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
                    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
                  };

                  $scope.toggleMin();

                  $scope.open1 = function() {
                    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
                  };


                  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
                    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
                  };

                  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
                  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
                  $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

                  $scope.popup1 = {
                    opened: false
                  };


                  var tomorrow = new Date();
                  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
                  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
                  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
                  $scope.events = [
                    {
                      date: tomorrow,
                      status: 'full'
                    },
                    {
                      date: afterTomorrow,
                      status: 'partially'
                    }
                  ];
                  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode){

                    $scope.holidays = [
                      new Date(2016,2,14),
                      new Date(2016,2,15),
                      new Date(2016,2,16),
                      new Date()
                    ]

                    var isHoliday = false;
                    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.holidays.length ; i++) {
                      if(areDatesEqual($scope.holidays[i], date)){
                        isHoliday = true;
                      }
                    }

                    return ( mode === 'day' && isHoliday );
                  };

                  function areDatesEqual(date1, date2) {

                    return date1.setHours(0,0,0,0) === date2.setHours(0,0,0,0)

                  }

                  $scope.dayClass = function(date, mode) {

                var appointments = [
                  new Date(2016,2,3),
                  new Date(2016,2,8),
                  new Date(2016,2,22),
                ]

                if (mode === 'day') {

                  var dateToCheck = new Date(date);

                  for(var i = 0; i < appointments.length ; i++) {
                    if(areDatesEqual(appointments[i], dateToCheck)){
                      return 'appointment';
                    }
                  }
                }
                return '';
              };

              $scope.dateSelected = function(){

        var appointments = [
          new Date(2016,2,3),
          new Date(2016,2,8),
          new Date(2016,2,22),
        ];

        var dateSelected = new Date($scope.dt);

        for(var i = 0; i < appointments.length ; i++) {
          if(areDatesEqual(appointments[i], dateSelected)){
            performAction();
          }
        }

      };

      function performAction(){
        alert("Appointment date selected");
      }


     $scope.dtmax = new Date();
                 });
```

siteDatepicker.html:

```
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>Typehead</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
          <script src="./siteDatePicker.js"></script>

              <style>
              .full button span {
                background-color: limegreen;
                border-radius: 32px;
                color: black;
              }
              .partially button span {
                background-color: orange;
                border-radius: 32px;
                color: black;
              }
              .appointment>button {
                color: white;
                background-color: red;
              }

            </style>   

          </head>
          <body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" >

             <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
              <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

              <h4>Popup</h4>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" ng-change="dateSelected()"is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" custom-class="dayClass(date, mode)"  max-date="dtmax" min-date="dtmax"/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

to all the helping hands...thank you!
special mention to avesh Naik and Nazeef Shaikh!

Comment: I just tried to implement your code but it isn't working meaning am not able to select the appointment dates. Please advise if am missing something.