# Angular Bootstrap Datepicker - Disable all dates except a specified list

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I've been stuck on this issue for a couple of days now and I cannot find any suitable example online to help. I am getting a list of dates from a rest service that I need to make available within the angular datepicker to be selected. When I have this list I need to disable every other date in the datepicker. Here is my current code examples to show this -

Here is a plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/8zncfr2VBayaO7wRFV4C?p=preview

HTML SNIPPET---

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="calender">
    <h3 class="map_tab_title"> Select Days </h3>
    <div uib-datepicker ng-model="date_pick" datepicker-options="options" date-disabled="disabled(data)">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn book_now_btn" ng-click="goToBookPage()">final step <span> input your information </span>    
    </button>
</div>
```

ANGULAR SNIPPET -

```
$scope.dates = response.data.outgoing.dates;
$scope.date_pick = Date.parse($scope.dates[0]);

$scope.today = function(){
    $scope.date_pick = new Date();
};
$scope.today();
$scope.options = {
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: false
};

function areDatesEqual(date1, date2) {
    return date1 == date2;
}
$scope.disabled = function(data) {
    console.log("TRIGGERED");
    var date = data.date,
        mode = data.mode;
    var isRealDate = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dates.length; i++) {
        if (areDatesEqual($scope.dates[i], date)) {
            isRealDate = true;
        }
    }                
    return (mode === 'day' && isRealDate);
};
```

Can someone please help me with this. I am at a loss. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244859/disable-all-dates-on-load-of-calendar-and-enable-specific-dates-in-angularjs-on) sounds very similar to what you are after.

Comment: Thanks @Lex - I've seen this and have tried to implement it but it doesn't seem to work for me at all.

Comment: can you give a plunker or the data which you are trying to compare in your for loop in disabled function ? somethin !

Comment: hi @Angular_10 - Just added a plunker to the question.

Comment: Also, as a note - the console log "Triggered" doesn't ever seem to fire unless I call it directly in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Hans for your answer - Here's what worked for me in the end -

https://plnkr.co/edit/P9bF18XemufyLXN75b7k?p=preview

HTML SNIPPET --

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <h3> Select Days </h3>
    <div uib-datepicker ng-model="date_pick" datepicker-options="options">  
   </div>
</div>
```

ANGULAR SNIPPET --

```
$scope.dates = ["2016-09-26", "2016-09-28", "2016-09-29"];
$scope.date_pick = Date.parse($scope.dates[0]);

$scope.today = function() {
  $scope.date_pick = new Date();
};
$scope.today();

$scope.options = {
  dateDisabled: disabledTest,
  showWeeks: false
};

var dayDuration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;

function areDatesEqual(date1, date2) {
  return (parseInt(date1 / dayDuration)) == (parseInt(date2 / dayDuration));
}

function disabledTest(data) {
  var date = data.date,
    mode = data.mode;

  var isRealDate = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dates.length; i++) {
    var changedDate = Date.parse($scope.dates[i]);
    if (areDatesEqual(changedDate, date)) {
      isRealDate = true;
    }
  }
  return mode === 'day' && !isRealDate; // && (date >= $scope.endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you've made mistake.
dateDisable is a date-picker option and you can implement function for dateDisable.

Here's little change based on your script.js

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])
.controller("MainController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.dates = ["9/26/2016", "9/28/2016", "9/29/2016"];
  $scope.date_pick = Date.parse($scope.dates[0]);

  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.date_pick = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();
  function areDatesEqual(date1, date2) {
    return date1 == date2.toLocaleDateString()
  }

  // *******we don't need this code*******//
  $scope.disable = function(data) {
    var date = data.date, mode= data.mode;
    var isRealDate = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dates.length; i++) {
      if (areDatesEqual($scope.dates[i], date)) {
        isRealDate = true;
      }
    }
    return (mode === 'day' && isRealDate);
  };
  //**************//

  $scope.options = {
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: false,
    //**********************************
    //// Here's changed part - add new option dateDisabled
    dateDisabled:function(data) {
      console.log("here")
      var date = data.date, mode= data.mode;
      var isRealDate = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dates.length; i++) {
        if (areDatesEqual($scope.dates[i], date)) {
          isRealDate = true;
        }
      }
      return (mode === 'day' && isRealDate);
    }
  };
}]);
```

And the changes in HTML code

```
<div uib-datepicker ng-model="date_pick" datepicker-options="options">
```

Comment: Yes, got below solution there - very similar to the one you posted here for free :D

Comment: yeah actually it's same but little change in checking date :)

Comment: If you have any problem or work please don't hesitate to contact me

Comment: @HansBrunner Please [edit] your answer to explain the little change you made to the asker's code.

Comment: @dorukayhan I've changed answer. Let me know if you have any question

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old questions, but I have been struggling with this problem recently and I want to share my working plunker, with what I think that is a cleaner solution:

http://embed.plnkr.co/pf5Kw2/